# What is the relation between row sums and the kernel for these matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a symmetric matrix $M\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ with non-negative off-diagonal entries and a unique positive eigenvalue of multiplicity one. Let $e_1,...,e_d\in\Bbb R^n$ be a basis of the kernel of $M$.

> **Is the following true?**
>
> If the sum of the $i$-th row of $M$ is negative, then the $i$-th component of
> $e_j$ is zero, for all $j\in\{1,...,d\}$.

This is a follow up on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4626474/415941).

Comment: Does $M$ have only one positive eigenvalue that is simple, i.e. all other eigenvalues are nonpositive? Or it just has *a* simple positive eigenvalue, i.e. it may have other positive eigenvalues, but they are not simple?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. All other eigenvalues are non-positive.